# Replacement IC for SGM2212 LDO Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, components, pcb-assembly

I'm looking for a suitable replacement IC for the SGM2212-3.3XKC3G/TR found in [this schematic](https://dl.espressif.com/dl/schematics/SCH_ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1_V1.1_20221130.pdf). I've found [this](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/toshiba-semiconductor-and-storage/TCR8BM33A-L3F/16678199), which seems to be very similar and suitable for this application, but I'd like if someone could double check. If this is not a good replacement, any suggestions on what might be? The incoming voltage is 5-5.2V from a USB/Buck-boost, and must output 3.3V @ at least 800mA, for an esp32. The footprint/package does not need to match the original. Any help is appreciated.

The average current consumption for the MCU used seems to be about 120mA, but can briefly spike to about 400mA.

Comment: That microscopic replacement will be limited to low power dissipation and almost certainly not be able to provide anywhere near the same average power. You didn't mention how much average current you need, but I would probably pick something rated close to the original part unless you're sure the original part was overspeced

Comment: The Toshiba part's datasheet is pretty vague about \$V_{BIAS}\$. I couldn't find any firm information about what potential it should have, if it can be left unconnected, or if it should be grounded. If it were me, I'd try and find a 3.3V LDO regulator with a datasheet I could actually understand. One with *complete*, working reference schematics, and better details. I'm sure the TCR8BM is a great part, when you know how to use it, but there are simpler devices that fit your needs.

Comment: Additionally, how important is PSRR to things? The MCU I'm using is an [esp32](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-2_datasheet_en.pdf) I'm not really sure how sensitive these things are. Would a 5db difference at 120Hz be an issue?  This is a hobby/learning project, and my first time attempting to use an MCU in a project without soldering in a devboard, so all these part replacement decisions are kind of difficult for me, as I can't find a source for many of the parts listed. Tysm for the help!

Comment: Since you're running off a switching power supply the 120 Hz PSRR doesn't matter, you don't have mains ripple to reject. You'd care about the psrr at the switching frequency, probably ~100khz. Usually though this is not a serious concern unless you have analog electronics (e.g. opamp). Since you're only looking at about 200mW you have a lot of options. Personally I like sot23 LDOs with generic pinouts, since I can swap out models if there's a shortage.